# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the fo llowing

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I get this error:

```
[sqlplus] Truncating dimension dw_DM_Application
[sqlplus] END;
[sqlplus] *
[sqlplus] ERROR at line 190:
[sqlplus] ORA-06550: line 190, column 1:
[sqlplus] PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
[sqlplus] begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
[sqlplus] raise return select update while with <an identifier>
[sqlplus] <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
[sqlplus] close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
[sqlplus] savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
```

For the following code and I Have no idea what is causing this ugly error:

```
DECLARE
StartDate DATE;
EndDate DATE;

PROCEDURE DM_Application_Full_Refresh IS    

    v_RecordStatus VARCHAR2(10);    

BEGIN
v_RecordStatus:='Normal';

 INSERT INTO dw_DM_Application
     (
      dmApplicationkey,
      vRecordStatus,         
      nApplicationId,
      nPostingTargetId,
      nCandidateProfileId,
      nOpeningId,
      nJobselectionProcessId,
      vApplicationStatus,
      dApplicationDate,
      bManually,
      vOrigin,
      bArchived,
      dCreationDate,
      dCreationDateMM,
      dUpdateDate,
      dUpdateDateMM,
      bActiveApplication,
      vApplicationSrcType,
      vSrcChannelName,
      vSourcingMedium,
      nJobDeptlevel1Id,
      nJobDeptlevel2Id,
      nJobDeptlevel3Id,
      bJobIsArchived,
      bJobIsGeneralApp,
      nJobRecruitingUser1Id,
      nJobRecruitingUser2Id,
      nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
      vJobCountry,
      vJobRegion,                                
      vJobContractType,
      vCandType,                 
      vCandGender,

      dHireDate,

      dHireDateMM
     )
SELECT row_number() over (order by 1),
       v_RecordStatus,
       a.*
FROM (
 SELECT /*+ use_nl(a cp) INDEX(a IDX_RLSH_25_FK_) index (cp pk_candidateprofile) */
    a.nApplicationId,
    a.nPostingTargetId,
    a.nCandidateProfileId,
    a.nOpeningId,
    a.nSelectionProcessId nJobSelectionProcessId,
    a.vApplicationStatus,
    a.dApplicationDate,
    a.bManually,
    a.sOrigin vOrigin,
    0 bArchived,  -- Not archived
    TRUNC(a.dCreationDate) dCreationDate,
    TRUNC(a.dCreationDate, 'MM') dCreationDateMM,
    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dUpdateDate,
    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dUpdateDateMM,
    a.bActiveApplication,
    a.vApplicationSrcType,
    NVL(a.sOrigin,DECODE(a.bManually,0,'-',1,'TalentLink',a.bManually)) SrcChannelName,
    a.vSourcingMedium,
    (Select nDepartmentid From Department where nlevel = 1
       Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel1Id, 
    (Select nDepartmentID From Department where nlevel = 2
       Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentID = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel2Id,
    (Select nDepartmentid FROM Department WHERE nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID AND nlevel = 3) DeptLevel3Id,
    o.bArchived bJobIsArchived, 
    o.bSpontaneousOpening bJobIsGeneralapp,
    o.nRecruitingUserId nJobRecruitingUser1Id, 
    o.nRecruitingUserId2 nJobRecruitingUser2Id, 
    o.nRecruitingUserId3 nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
    o.vCountry JobCountry,
    o.vRegion JobRegion,     
    o.vContractType JobContractType,
    cp.vCandidateType,
    DECODE(cp.vSex, 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', '-') CandGender,

    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dHireDate,
    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dHireDateMM
  FROM Application a, Opening o, CandidateProfile cp
  WHERE a.nOpeningId=o.nOpeningId
    AND a.nCandidateProfileid=cp.nCandidateProfileid
 UNION ALL
  SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ 
   a.nApplicationIdH nApplicationId,
   a.nPostingTargetIdH nPostingTargetId,
   a.nCandidateProfileIdH nCandidateProfileId,
   a.nOpeningId,
   a.nSelectionProcessId nJobselectionProcessId,
   a.vApplicationStatus,
   a.dApplicationDate,
   a.bManually,
   a.sOrigin vOrigin,
   1 bArchived,  -- Archived
   TRUNC(a.dCreationDate) dCreationDate,
   TRUNC(a.dCreationDate, 'MM') dCreationDateMM,
   TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dUpdateDate,
  TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dUpdateDateMM,
   a.bActiveApplication,
   a.vApplicationSrcType,
   NVL(a.sOrigin,DECODE(a.bManually,0,'-',1,'TalentLink',a.bManually)) SrcChannelName,
   a.vSourcingMedium,
   (Select nDepartmentid From Department where nlevel = 1
      Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel1Id, 
   (Select nDepartmentID From Department where nlevel = 2
      Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentID = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel2Id,
   (Select nDepartmentid FROM Department WHERE nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID AND nlevel = 3) DeptLevel3Id, 
   o.bArchived bJobIsArchived, 
   o.bSpontaneousOpening bJobIsGeneralapp,
   o.nRecruitingUserId nJobRecruitingUser1Id, 
   o.nRecruitingUserId2 nJobRecruitingUser2Id, 
   o.nRecruitingUserId3 nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
   o.vCountry JobCountry,      
   o.vRegion JobRegion,                        
   o.vContractType JobContractType,
   cp.vCandidateType,
   DECODE(cp.vSex, 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', NULL) CandGender,

   TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dHireDate,
  TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dHireDateMM

FROM ApplicationH a, Opening o, CandidateProfileH cp
WHERE a.nOpeningId=o.nOpeningId
  AND a.nCandidateProfileidH=cp.nCandidateProfileidH
  AND cp.nCandidateProfileidH > 0) a;       
END;

BEGIN
SELECT SYSDATE
INTO StartDate
FROM DUAL;

 DM_Application_Full_Refresh;

 COMMIT;

 SELECT SYSDATE
 INTO EndDate
 FROM DUAL; 

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Full refresh of DW_DM_APPLICATION finished. Time: '|| TO_CHAR(ROUND((EndDate-StartDate)*3600*24)));

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Errors occured: '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM(SQLCODE),1, 200));

 END;
 /
```

Comment: I do have a declare statement before the procedure starts so I have edited the original question now. I still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

You have two pieces of code there:

1. Code to define a procedure
2. Code to run that procedure

However, you have run them together, which Oracle doesn't like.  I'm not sure if you wanted to create a stored procedure, or just define a procedure temporarily and run it?  If the latter then this will do it:

```
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE DM_Application_Full_Refresh IS    

        v_RecordStatus VARCHAR2(10);    

    BEGIN
    v_RecordStatus:='Normal';

     INSERT INTO dw_DM_Application
         (
          dmApplicationkey,
          vRecordStatus,         
          nApplicationId,
          nPostingTargetId,
          nCandidateProfileId,
          nOpeningId,
          nJobselectionProcessId,
          vApplicationStatus,
          dApplicationDate,
          bManually,
          vOrigin,
          bArchived,
          dCreationDate,
          dCreationDateMM,
          dUpdateDate,
          dUpdateDateMM,
          bActiveApplication,
          vApplicationSrcType,
          vSrcChannelName,
          vSourcingMedium,
          nJobDeptlevel1Id,
          nJobDeptlevel2Id,
          nJobDeptlevel3Id,
          bJobIsArchived,
          bJobIsGeneralApp,
          nJobRecruitingUser1Id,
          nJobRecruitingUser2Id,
          nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
          vJobCountry,
          vJobRegion,                                
          vJobContractType,
          vCandType,                 
          vCandGender,

          dHireDate,

          dHireDateMM
         )
    SELECT row_number() over (order by 1),
           v_RecordStatus,
           a.*
    FROM (
     SELECT /*+ use_nl(a cp) INDEX(a IDX_RLSH_25_FK_) index (cp pk_candidateprofile) */
        a.nApplicationId,
        a.nPostingTargetId,
        a.nCandidateProfileId,
        a.nOpeningId,
        a.nSelectionProcessId nJobSelectionProcessId,
        a.vApplicationStatus,
        a.dApplicationDate,
        a.bManually,
        a.sOrigin vOrigin,
        0 bArchived,  -- Not archived
        TRUNC(a.dCreationDate) dCreationDate,
        TRUNC(a.dCreationDate, 'MM') dCreationDateMM,
        TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dUpdateDate,
        TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dUpdateDateMM,
        a.bActiveApplication,
        a.vApplicationSrcType,
        NVL(a.sOrigin,DECODE(a.bManually,0,'-',1,'TalentLink',a.bManually)) SrcChannelName,
        a.vSourcingMedium,
        (Select nDepartmentid From Department where nlevel = 1
           Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel1Id, 
        (Select nDepartmentID From Department where nlevel = 2
           Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentID = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel2Id,
        (Select nDepartmentid FROM Department WHERE nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID AND nlevel = 3) DeptLevel3Id,
        o.bArchived bJobIsArchived, 
        o.bSpontaneousOpening bJobIsGeneralapp,
        o.nRecruitingUserId nJobRecruitingUser1Id, 
        o.nRecruitingUserId2 nJobRecruitingUser2Id, 
        o.nRecruitingUserId3 nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
        o.vCountry JobCountry,
        o.vRegion JobRegion,     
        o.vContractType JobContractType,
        cp.vCandidateType,
        DECODE(cp.vSex, 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', '-') CandGender,

        TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dHireDate,
        TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dHireDateMM
      FROM Application a, Opening o, CandidateProfile cp
      WHERE a.nOpeningId=o.nOpeningId
        AND a.nCandidateProfileid=cp.nCandidateProfileid
     UNION ALL
      SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ 
       a.nApplicationIdH nApplicationId,
       a.nPostingTargetIdH nPostingTargetId,
       a.nCandidateProfileIdH nCandidateProfileId,
       a.nOpeningId,
       a.nSelectionProcessId nJobselectionProcessId,
       a.vApplicationStatus,
       a.dApplicationDate,
       a.bManually,
       a.sOrigin vOrigin,
       1 bArchived,  -- Archived
       TRUNC(a.dCreationDate) dCreationDate,
       TRUNC(a.dCreationDate, 'MM') dCreationDateMM,
       TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dUpdateDate,
      TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dUpdateDateMM,
       a.bActiveApplication,
       a.vApplicationSrcType,
       NVL(a.sOrigin,DECODE(a.bManually,0,'-',1,'TalentLink',a.bManually)) SrcChannelName,
       a.vSourcingMedium,
       (Select nDepartmentid From Department where nlevel = 1
          Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel1Id, 
       (Select nDepartmentID From Department where nlevel = 2
          Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentID = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel2Id,
       (Select nDepartmentid FROM Department WHERE nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID AND nlevel = 3) DeptLevel3Id, 
       o.bArchived bJobIsArchived, 
       o.bSpontaneousOpening bJobIsGeneralapp,
       o.nRecruitingUserId nJobRecruitingUser1Id, 
       o.nRecruitingUserId2 nJobRecruitingUser2Id, 
       o.nRecruitingUserId3 nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
       o.vCountry JobCountry,      
       o.vRegion JobRegion,                        
       o.vContractType JobContractType,
       cp.vCandidateType,
       DECODE(cp.vSex, 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', NULL) CandGender,

       TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dHireDate,
      TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dHireDateMM

    FROM ApplicationH a, Opening o, CandidateProfileH cp
    WHERE a.nOpeningId=o.nOpeningId
      AND a.nCandidateProfileidH=cp.nCandidateProfileidH
      AND cp.nCandidateProfileidH > 0) a;       
    END;

BEGIN
    SELECT SYSDATE
    INTO StartDate
    FROM DUAL;

     DM_Application_Full_Refresh;

     COMMIT;

     SELECT SYSDATE
     INTO EndDate
     FROM DUAL; 

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Full refresh of DW_DM_APPLICATION finished. Time: '|| TO_CHAR(ROUND((EndDate-StartDate)*3600*24)));

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Errors occured: '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM(SQLCODE),1, 200));

END;
/
```

If you did want a permanent stored procedure then do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE DM_Application_Full_Refresh IS    

    v_RecordStatus VARCHAR2(10);    

BEGIN
v_RecordStatus:='Normal';

 INSERT INTO dw_DM_Application
     (
      dmApplicationkey,
      vRecordStatus,         
      nApplicationId,
      nPostingTargetId,
      nCandidateProfileId,
      nOpeningId,
      nJobselectionProcessId,
      vApplicationStatus,
      dApplicationDate,
      bManually,
      vOrigin,
      bArchived,
      dCreationDate,
      dCreationDateMM,
      dUpdateDate,
      dUpdateDateMM,
      bActiveApplication,
      vApplicationSrcType,
      vSrcChannelName,
      vSourcingMedium,
      nJobDeptlevel1Id,
      nJobDeptlevel2Id,
      nJobDeptlevel3Id,
      bJobIsArchived,
      bJobIsGeneralApp,
      nJobRecruitingUser1Id,
      nJobRecruitingUser2Id,
      nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
      vJobCountry,
      vJobRegion,                                
      vJobContractType,
      vCandType,                 
      vCandGender,

      dHireDate,

      dHireDateMM
     )
SELECT row_number() over (order by 1),
       v_RecordStatus,
       a.*
FROM (
 SELECT /*+ use_nl(a cp) INDEX(a IDX_RLSH_25_FK_) index (cp pk_candidateprofile) */
    a.nApplicationId,
    a.nPostingTargetId,
    a.nCandidateProfileId,
    a.nOpeningId,
    a.nSelectionProcessId nJobSelectionProcessId,
    a.vApplicationStatus,
    a.dApplicationDate,
    a.bManually,
    a.sOrigin vOrigin,
    0 bArchived,  -- Not archived
    TRUNC(a.dCreationDate) dCreationDate,
    TRUNC(a.dCreationDate, 'MM') dCreationDateMM,
    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dUpdateDate,
    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dUpdateDateMM,
    a.bActiveApplication,
    a.vApplicationSrcType,
    NVL(a.sOrigin,DECODE(a.bManually,0,'-',1,'TalentLink',a.bManually)) SrcChannelName,
    a.vSourcingMedium,
    (Select nDepartmentid From Department where nlevel = 1
       Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel1Id, 
    (Select nDepartmentID From Department where nlevel = 2
       Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentID = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel2Id,
    (Select nDepartmentid FROM Department WHERE nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID AND nlevel = 3) DeptLevel3Id,
    o.bArchived bJobIsArchived, 
    o.bSpontaneousOpening bJobIsGeneralapp,
    o.nRecruitingUserId nJobRecruitingUser1Id, 
    o.nRecruitingUserId2 nJobRecruitingUser2Id, 
    o.nRecruitingUserId3 nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
    o.vCountry JobCountry,
    o.vRegion JobRegion,     
    o.vContractType JobContractType,
    cp.vCandidateType,
    DECODE(cp.vSex, 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', '-') CandGender,

    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dHireDate,
    TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dHireDateMM
  FROM Application a, Opening o, CandidateProfile cp
  WHERE a.nOpeningId=o.nOpeningId
    AND a.nCandidateProfileid=cp.nCandidateProfileid
 UNION ALL
  SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ 
   a.nApplicationIdH nApplicationId,
   a.nPostingTargetIdH nPostingTargetId,
   a.nCandidateProfileIdH nCandidateProfileId,
   a.nOpeningId,
   a.nSelectionProcessId nJobselectionProcessId,
   a.vApplicationStatus,
   a.dApplicationDate,
   a.bManually,
   a.sOrigin vOrigin,
   1 bArchived,  -- Archived
   TRUNC(a.dCreationDate) dCreationDate,
   TRUNC(a.dCreationDate, 'MM') dCreationDateMM,
   TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dUpdateDate,
  TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dUpdateDateMM,
   a.bActiveApplication,
   a.vApplicationSrcType,
   NVL(a.sOrigin,DECODE(a.bManually,0,'-',1,'TalentLink',a.bManually)) SrcChannelName,
   a.vSourcingMedium,
   (Select nDepartmentid From Department where nlevel = 1
      Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel1Id, 
   (Select nDepartmentID From Department where nlevel = 2
      Connect by prior nFatherDptID = nDepartmentID start with nDepartmentID = o.nDepartmentID) DeptLevel2Id,
   (Select nDepartmentid FROM Department WHERE nDepartmentid = o.nDepartmentID AND nlevel = 3) DeptLevel3Id, 
   o.bArchived bJobIsArchived, 
   o.bSpontaneousOpening bJobIsGeneralapp,
   o.nRecruitingUserId nJobRecruitingUser1Id, 
   o.nRecruitingUserId2 nJobRecruitingUser2Id, 
   o.nRecruitingUserId3 nJobRecruitingUser3Id,
   o.vCountry JobCountry,      
   o.vRegion JobRegion,                        
   o.vContractType JobContractType,
   cp.vCandidateType,
   DECODE(cp.vSex, 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', NULL) CandGender,

   TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate) dHireDate,
  TRUNC(a.dUpdateDate, 'MM') dHireDateMM

FROM ApplicationH a, Opening o, CandidateProfileH cp
WHERE a.nOpeningId=o.nOpeningId
  AND a.nCandidateProfileidH=cp.nCandidateProfileidH
  AND cp.nCandidateProfileidH > 0) a;       
END;
/
```

And then do this to run it:

```
BEGIN
SELECT SYSDATE
INTO StartDate
FROM DUAL;

 DM_Application_Full_Refresh;

 COMMIT;

 SELECT SYSDATE
 INTO EndDate
 FROM DUAL; 

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Full refresh of DW_DM_APPLICATION finished. Time: '|| TO_CHAR(ROUND((EndDate-StartDate)*3600*24)));

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Errors occured: '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM(SQLCODE),1, 200));

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it should compile and run.

The error message says line 190, but there aren't 190 lines in your sample.  Are we not looking at the real code?

Also, you should remove the EXCEPTION block.  SQL*Plus automatically displays all the debugging information you need.